# equivalent properties of cardinals

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Let $A\neq \emptyset$ be a set. Show that the following are equivalent:

1. $|\mathbb{N}| = \aleph_0\leq |A|$
2. $|A| = n|A|$ for any $n\geq 2\in \mathbb{N}$
3. $|A| = \aleph_0 |A|$

I want to show $(1)\Rightarrow (2)\Rightarrow (3)\Rightarrow (1).$

$(1)\Rightarrow (2)$. Suppose $(1)$ holds. Then there is an injection $f : \mathbb{N}\to A.$ It suffices to show that $|A| = |A| + |A| = |A\times 2| = |A\times \{0\}\cup A\times \{1\}|$, where $2 = \{0,1\},$ since an inductive argument can be applied to give the required result. So we need to define a bijection $f : A \to A\times 2.$ Let $\mathcal{F} := \{(X,f) : X\subseteq A, f : X\to X\times 2\text{ is a bijection}\}.$ Observe that $\mathcal{F}$ is nonempty because $A$ contains a denumerable subset $X$, and thus there exists a bijection $f : X\to X\times 2.$ Order the elements of $\mathcal{F}$ by extension. That is, let $(X_1, f_1) \leq (X_2, f_2)$ if $X_1\subseteq X_2$ and $f_2\vert_{X_1} = f_1$. Let $C = \{(X_i, f_i)\}_{i\in I}$  be a chain in $\mathcal{F}.$ Let $X = \cup_{i\in I} X_i$ and $f : X\to X\times 2$ be defined so that $f(x) = f_i(x),$ where $i\in I$ is so that $x\in X_i.$ Then note that $(X,f)$ is an upper bound for $C,$ and is in $\mathcal{F}.$ So by Zorn's Lemma, $\mathcal{F}$ has a maximal element, say $(Y, g).$ Suppose $|Y| < |A|.$ Then $|A\backslash Y| = |A| - |Y| = |A|.$ So $A\backslash Y$ has a denumerable subset $Z.$ Since $Z$ is denumerable, there is a bijection $h : Z\to Z\times 2.$ Then let $i : Y\cup Z\to (Y\cup Z)\times 2, i(w) = \begin{cases}g(w),&\text{ if $w \in Y$}\\
h(w),&\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$
Then $(Y,g) < (Y\cup Z, i),$ a contradiction. So $|Y| = |A|.$ Hence $|A| = |Y| = |Y\times 2| = |Y| + |Y| = |A| + |A|,$ as required.

$(2)\Rightarrow (3).$ One can find a bijection between $\{1,\cdots, n\}\times A$ and $\{1,\cdots, n+1\}\times A$ for any $n\geq 1$, since $n|A| = (n+1)|A|$ (indeed $n|A| = |A|$ so $(n+1)|A| = n|A| + |A| = |A| + |A| = |A|$). Hence, one can find a bijection between $\{1\}\times A$ and $\mathbb{N}\times A,$ which implies $|A| = |\{1\}\times A| = |\mathbb{N}\times A| = \aleph_0 |A|.$

$(3)\Rightarrow (1).$ If $|A| = \aleph_0 |A|,$ then there is a bijection $f : A \to \mathbb{N}\times A.$ Fix $a \in A$ and let $h : \mathbb{N}\to A, h(b) = f^{-1} (b,a).$ Observe that $h$ is injective because if $b\neq d,$ then since $f^{-1}$ is injective, $h(b) = f^{-1}(b,a) \neq f^{-1}(d, a) = h(d).$ Thus, $\aleph_0 \leq |A|.$

> Is this incorrect? Especially $(2)\Rightarrow (3)$ and $(3)\Rightarrow (1).$ Also, WHY is $f$ well-defined in $(1)$? If I choose $i\in I$ randomly, isn't it possible that $x\neq y $ but $x\in X_i$ and $y \in X_j, i\neq j$ and $f_i(x) = f_j(y)$?

Comment: Your $3\to 1$ is correct, but $2\to 3$ is not. There is no reason to assume $n|A|=(n+1)|A|$ for all $n$ implies $|A|=\aleph_0|A|$.

Comment: $1\to 2$ is a bit subtle: I think there is a more direct proof by assuming $Y\neq A$.

Comment: Your proof of (2) implies (3) is what I like to call "wishful proving". It's very common in undergraduate level courses, but unfortunately one can never really get rid of it throughout the career. You see the target, you know it's there, and so you make a logical leap. Your brain just covers the missing middle as "it makes sense", exactly because you know (or at least believe) that the conclusion is true. But try to fill in the details, and you'll see that you have a gap there.

Comment: (Interestingly enough, (2) and (3) are equivalent even in the absence of the axiom of choice, whereas the equivalence to (1) requires it. Which really tells you that the implication from (2) to (3) is something that can be done quite explicitly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1)$\implies$(2): The idea is very nice that we could in theory stop at any subset of cardinality $|A|$, however, I think, when you stated $|Y|<|A|\implies |A\setminus Y|=|A|$, you implicitly used the statement to be proved: $|Y|+|Y|=|Y|$
for infinite $|Y|$.
Instead, I think, we should prove that $Y=A$: suppose $f:Y\to Y\times 2$ is a bijection and $x\in A\setminus Y$, then we can shift one of the columns in a denumerable subset $Y_1$ of $Y$ in order to obtain a bijection $\,Y\cup\{x\}\,\longrightarrow \,(Y\cup\{x\})\times 2$.

(2)$\implies$(3): It's not correct.
By $2|A|=|A|$, we can cut $A$ into half: there are disjoint $A_0$ and $B_0$ such that
$|A_0|=|B_0|=|A|$ and $A=A_0\cup B_0$. This can be done with $B_0$ again, yielding $A_1$ and $B_1$, and then so on, cut $B_i$ to $A_{i+1},\ B_{i+1}$.

Fix bijections $h_n:A\to A_n$, then
map $(n,a)\in\Bbb N\times A$ to $h_n(a)$. This is a bijection to $\bigcup_nA_n\subseteq A$.

(3)$\implies$(1): It's correct.

Comment: I don't really understand your proof of $(1)\Rightarrow (2).$ In particular, what do you mean by "shifting one of the columns in a denumerable subset $Y_1$ of $Y$?" Does that use the fact that $Y_1\cup \{x\}$ is denumerable? Then one can find a bijection $f : Y_1\cup \{x\}\to (Y_1\cup \{x\})\times 2.$ But how does this show that $|Y\cup \{x\}| = |(Y\cup \{x\})\times 2|$? And can't I just show that $A\backslash Y$ is finite by a contradiction?

Comment: Also, why is the $f$ in my question well-defined?

Comment: @Alfred: For your first question, I find it easier to use the bijection $h=f^{-1}$. Let $Y_1=\{y_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. Extend $h$ to $\hat h:(Y\cup\{x\})\times 2\to Y\cup\{x\}$ as follows. $$\hat h(\langle y,i\rangle)=\begin{cases}x,&\text{if }y=x\text{ and }i=0\\h(\langle y_0,1\rangle),&\text{if }y=x\text{ and }i=1\\h(\langle y_{n+1},1\rangle),&\text{if }y=y_n\text{ and }i=1\\h(\langle y,i\rangle),&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Yes, I thought about something like this. Which $f$ in your question is to be well-defined? (There are no such problems, anyway.) However, I think, my proof for (2)$\implies$(3) is not correct as it is: the image of $(1,a)$ will be the same as of $(10_2,a')$ or $(11_2,a')$ for some $a'$ because $A_1=A_{10}\cup A_{11}$. I will edit if I find a better direct approach. Otherwise, using axiom of choice, there's a general proof for $|A\times A|=|A|$ if $A$ is infinite, and then it would follow...

Comment: @Berci I'm talking about the $f$ in the following part of my "justification" for $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$: Let $C = \{(X_i, f_i)\}_{i\in I}$  be a chain in $\mathcal{F}.$ Let $X = \cup_{i\in I} X_i$ and $f : X\to X\times 2$ be defined so that $f(x) = f_i(x),$ where $i\in I$ is so that $x\in X_i.$ Then note that $(X,f)$ is an upper bound for $C,$ and is in $\mathcal{F}.$

Comment: @Alfred: that $f$ is well defined: by the given partial order: if $x\in X_i\cap X_j$, supposed $i<j$, then $f_i=f_j|_{X_i}$ so $f_j(x)=f_i(x)$.

Comment: I edited my proof for (2)$\implies$(3).